# Using lerna as an API version manager

Tags: node.js, lerna

I'm trying to version my API (/v1/route, /v2/route...) with a different approach, and I feel that [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) would be able to do the job.

The code structure is in the format:

```
src/
  commons/
    common files // files that can be used in any version.
  v1/
    code modules // files corresponding to v1 of API
    package.json
    package-lock.json
  v2/
    code modules // files corresponding to v2 of API
    package.json
    package-lock.json
lerna.json
package.json
package-lock.json
server.js
```

lerna.json:

```
{
  "packages": ["src/**"],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Basically, I have 2 goals:

- Each version should have its own independent node_modules/, and should use that. Common code, and code at root level of project should use node_modules/ from root of the project.
- Code should be started from server.js at the root of project. (`node server.js`)

Let's also consider that:

```
- package.json at root of the folder has packageA (v1.0.0), packageB (v1.0.0), packageC (v1.0.0). It also has all the scripts: start, test etc.
- package.json in v1 has packageA (v2.0.0), packageC (v3.0.0). No scripts.
- package.json in v2 has packageB (v1.0.0), packageC (v3.0.0). No scripts.
```

I've tried installing the root packages with `npm i` and then `lerna bootstrap`. Then tried starting the server with `node server.js`, which was stupid of me because the control should be passed to lerna to do this. So I tried `lerna run start`, which also failed because none of the versioned packages have the script to start the server.

I cannot provide the versioned packages the script to start the server because the server is common for all the versions of code.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve? Is this a good way to move ahead?

Thanks.